# With out any data loss, how can we interchange hashtable key values?

Tags: java

I have been facing a question frequently regarding Hashtable.

How to convert key as value and value as key with out any data loss using `java.util.Hashtable.`

```
 Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

        ht.put(1,"One");
        ht.put(2,"Two");
        ht.put(3,"One");
```

I would like to convert keys as "One","Two","One" and values as 1,2,3 respectively.

Thanks for your valuable support.

Comment: need to achieve programatically, so you need to iterate loo get the entry and store to temp variable remove it and then insert it again

Comment: it looks to me as if the example data would be typed Int keys and String values.  This would be a problem.  You'd probably have to have a String to String hashtable

Comment: You can create a new `HashTable` and iterate over previous table and put key as value and value as key.

Comment: @Vorsprung by not specifying the generic types you in effect get `Hashtable<Object, Object>` which will allow the keys and values to be swapped.

Comment: "How to convert key as value and value as key with out any data loss" 
I think it cannot be done according to example. While keyset is unique (no one key is present more than once), value set is duplicate (for keys 1 and 3). So swapping keys and values will result in HashTable with only two records.

Comment: Is using Guava's [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) an option?

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to do this (by which I mean avoiding the situation where there is already a key that is equal to one of the values in the `Hashtable` as in your example with the value `"one"`) is to copy to a new `Hashtable`, something like this:

```
Map copy = new Hashtable();

for (Map.Entry entry : original.entrySet())
{
  copy.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
}
```

Then if you really need to get the keys and values back in the original, just do:

```
original.clear();
original.putAll(copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hashtable<Object, Object> ht1 = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();

    ht1.put(1, "One");
    ht1.put(2, "Two");
    ht1.put(3, "One");

    Hashtable<Object, Object> ht2 = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
    for (Object key : ht1.keySet()) 
    {
        Object value = ht1.get(key);    
        ht2.put(new Temp(value.toString()), key);
    }    
    ht1.clear();    
    ht1.putAll(ht2);

}
```

**EDIT**

```
class Temp
{
    String str1;
    public Temp(String str1) {
    this.str1 = str1;
    }
}
```

by providing reference type that is object of class Temp you can avoid data loss.

Comment: I think you've modified OP's example a bit. In original post, there is ht.put(3,"One"); which will provide a different output, than your modified example - it will produce a data loss, that OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Thanks @JiriKusa for your attention, I have corrected the code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic implementation that iterates over the entry set:

```
public static <K, V> Hashtable<V, K> reverseEntries(Hashtable<K, V> in) {
    Hashtable<V, K> out = new Hashtable<V, K>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : in.entrySet())
        out.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
    return out;
}
```

Iterating over the entry set is the most efficient way to iterate over all entries because you get the key and value together (iterating over keys means you have to look up the entry for every key).

Answer (score 0):

Google Guava has the [BiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) interface with [HashBiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html) as an implementation:

```
BiMap<Integer,String> map = new HashBiMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(1, "One");
map.put(2, "Two");
map.put(3, "One");
```

However, this "preserves the uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys" (it is backed by two `HashMap`s), so in your particular case it wouldn't work, as two values are "One".

If you need this functionality then using Guava is probably the best way to approach it, but if you would rather understand how to implement this then looking at the source code of `HashBiMap` may also help.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to convert keys as "One","Two","One" and values as 1,2,3 respectively

This is simply impossible. A Hashtable only stores one value for each key.